# Custom view is not working

Tags: android, animation, view, rotation

I have this custom view class which i found to make a rotate animation for the imageView i have in my project:

```
public class RotatedTitle extends ImageView
{
private float angleRotation;

public RotatedTitle(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public RotatedTitle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RotatedTitle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setAngleRotation(float angleRotation)
{
    this.angleRotation = angleRotation;
    postInvalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{

    Rect clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(angleRotation, clipBounds.exactCenterX(), clipBounds.exactCenterY());
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
    postInvalidate();

}
}
```

Then am calling it like this in my main project:

```
RotatedTitle to = (RotatedTitle) findViewById(R.id.rotate);
    to.setAngleRotation(10);
```

nothing is happening at all !! I do get the image to be drawn on the screen but no animation is happening. I tried to change invalidate() to postInvalidate() but nothing worked. Where is exactly to problem ? why I cant get any rotation animation!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

But you can use just RotateAnimation() class provided by SDK

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Animation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 10.0f, pivotX, pivotY);
an.setDuration(5000);               
an.setFillAfter(true);        

image.setAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: the rotationAnimation is not giving me the goal am looking for. It only rotates the view around its own center. I want to have another type of rotation like having the image to rotate around a circle

Comment: @adnan You can change the pivot coordinates in order to rotate around ie. another object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to rotate a view, use the RotateAnimation class.  It was designed for this use.  See the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html

Comment: I did that before, my goal is to make the imageview rotate in circle. Like if its rotating around a circle not around it self which is what RotationAnimation does.

Comment: I see.  Another approach would be to use a translationY/translationX animation.

Comment: would this approach work for rotating views ? as far as I know, the translation animation is used for moving views